# Why can't I get wireless connections but I can get Internet on Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, kali-linux

So, when I try to connect to a WiFi network on Kali Linux, it won't give me any WiFi networks. But so long as the windows WiFi is connected, it will give me internet. So, I know the WiFi works somehow. What I don't know is why can't I get wireless networks to show up on Kali Linux terminal?

```
root@kali:~# iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Here are the contents of the file you asked for:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Post the contents of your /etc/network/interfaces file.  That may help to solve this problem.  Is this set up as a virtual machine?

Comment: It is set up as a virtual machine

Comment: I too can't connect to WiFis on my Kali Linux, but that's a hardware problem…

Answer (score 2):

i think , you are using kali linux in VM on any host machine (window ) . if i am right than it will not show wifi in VM . you have attached wifi device on host machine not in virtual machine. there is no wifi device attached on VM . you can access wifi in host system only . 
for VM(Kali machine) internet you have to do NAT , Bridge etc. 
that ip will show on `ifconfig` command in terminal .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a wlan0 connection to your /etc/network/interfaces file.

add:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

then: `sudo ifup wlan0`

You may have to restart the system.

Also the terminal program "wicd-curses" is very useful, you may want to install that to manage wireless access.